# WHERE clause before LEFT JOIN not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this working fine:

```
SELECT posts.*, members.username, categories.category_name
   FROM posts
   LEFT JOIN members
        ON posts.post.by = members.id
   LEFT JOIN categories
        ON posts.post_category = categories.category_id
   ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
   LIMIT $start, $limit
```

But I want this WHERE condition to it:

```
WHERE posts.post_by = 1
```

I can't figure out the right way to do it, I've tried placing it at the end, before LIMIT, after FROM posts but the results come back empty.

Comment: Have you confirmed you actually have an entry in the posts table with an id of 1?

Comment: Why would i need that? the condition is to get entries where the the column post_by = 1

Comment: Your post has a syntax error... should be `post_by`, not `post.by`, and that's what I mean, the posts.post_by column having a value of 1 (members_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` clause goes after the `from`:

```
                   SELECT posts.*, members.username, categories.category_name
                   FROM posts
                   LEFT JOIN members
                        ON posts.post.by = members.id
                   LEFT JOIN categories
                        ON posts.post_category = categories.category_id
                   WHERE posts.post_by = 1
                   ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
                   LIMIT $start, $limit;
```

The `join`s are part of the `from` clause, which is why I indent queries as:

```
                   SELECT posts.*, members.username, categories.category_name
                   FROM posts LEFT JOIN
                        members
                        ON posts.post.by = members.id LEFT JOIN
                        categories
                        ON posts.post_category = categories.category_id
                   WHERE posts.post_by = 1
                   ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
                   LIMIT $start, $limit;
```

Comment: You mean after the joins.

Comment: @juergend . . . No, I mean after the `from`.  `join`s are not a clause in SQL, they are a statement in the `from` clause.